# Gmail addon creation

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am creating a Gmail addon using apps script. Addon is now visible only when anyone opens a message, how can we show the addon after login to the gmail, that is on the right side of the inbox listing where all other addons are listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the official Gmail addons like Tasks and Keep are visible in the main view while all other addons can only be triggered manually when a message is opened by the user.

According to the [manifest structure](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/manifests#manifest_structure_for_gmail_add-ons) of Gmail addons, the gmail.contextualTriggers entry "defines a trigger that fires when the open email meets a specific criteria. When the trigger fires, it executes a specific Apps Script function, usually in order to create new cards and update the UI. Every add-on must define either a contextual trigger and/or a set of universal actions."